# Filtering with conditional conditions (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have an array with multiple strings, some of them are none(0 or ''), and each of them should have their own conditions **if exists**. if the array at its position is none, I don't have to apply the filtering.

```
# df.columns = ['a','b','c','d','e']

# Case 1 
l = ['A', 'B', '','' , 123]
## DESIRED FILTERING
df[ (df.a=='A') & (df.b=='B') & (df.e == 123)]

# Case 2
l = ['z','' ,'' ,'', 123]
## DESIRED FILTERING
df[ (df.a=='z') & (df.e == 123) ]
```

This is my attempt, yet it failed cuz `(df.col_name == 'something')` returns a series.

```
#Case 1 for example

check_null = [ i!='' for i in l ]       # ->returns [true,false,...]
conditions = [ (df.a==l[0]),(df.b==l[1]),(df.c==l[2]), (df.d==l[3]), (df.e==l[4])]
filt = [conditions[i] for i in range(len(check_null)) if check_null[i]]

df[filt]
```

How do I manage to get this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary for non empty values, convert to `Series` and filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a','b','c','d','e'])
df.loc[0] = ['A', 'B','g' ,'h' , 123]
df.loc[1] = ['A', 'B','g' ,'h' , 52]

l = ['A', 'B','' ,'' , 123]

s = pd.Series(dict(zip(df.columns, l))).loc[lambda x: x != '']

df  = df[df[s.index].eq(s).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   a  b  c  d    e
0  A  B  g  h  123
```

---

```
l = ['A', 'B', '','', '']
s = pd.Series(dict(zip(df.columns, l))).loc[lambda x: x != '']

df  = df[df[s.index].eq(s).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   a  b  c  d    e
0  A  B  g  h  123
1  A  B  g  h   52
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Series for comparison.

Either ensure that the value matches the Series (`df.eq(s)`), or (`|`) that the Series contains a empty string (`s.eq('')`). Broadcasting magic will do the rest ;)

```
s = pd.Series(l, index=df.columns)

df2 = df[(df.eq(s)|s.eq('')).all(1)]
```

Example with `['A', 'B', '', '', 123]`:

```
# input
   a  b  c  d    e
0  A  B  C  D  123
1  A  X  C  D  456

# output
   a  b  c  d    e
0  A  B  C  D  123
```